# file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages

Tags: laravel, google-maps, ssl, laravel-5, openssl

In my Laravel project, I am using the laravelgooglemaps api by farhanwazir on my "contact us" page to display a fixed location.

Route for contactus page:

```
Route::get('/contactus', function () {
      $config['center'] = 'California State University, Fullerton';
      $config['zoom']='15';
      $config['map_height'] = "300px";
      $config['map_width'] = "300px";
      $config['scrollwheel']= false;
      GMaps::initialize($config);
      $marker['position'] = 'California State University, Fullerton';
      $marker['infowindow_content'] = 'Easywash Centre';
      GMaps::add_marker($marker);
      $map = GMaps::create_map();
return view('contactus')->with('map', $map); });
```

In my `contactus.blade.php` file:

```
  {!! $map['html'] !!}
```

But sometimes when I load the "contact us" page I get the error:

> ErrorException (E_WARNING)
>   file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

[image]

Can anyone help me understand why I am getting such error and how it can be solved?

Comment: Probably your issue is related to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67842936

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Just in case anyone wondering I solved this error by changing https://  to http:// .

Comment: This isn't really solved, is it? Not if you need to use https/SSL

Comment: This wouldn't work in general, because most good websites will redirect `HTTP://` to `HTTPS://` and the client can not affect this.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$arrContextOptions=array(
            "ssl"=>array(
                "verify_peer"=>false,
                "verify_peer_name"=>false,
            ),
        );
file_get_contents($link, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue, it just hides it.